# How to setup Azure virtual machine port rules to allow PsExec traffic?

Tags: azure, security, psexec, windows-firewall

I run [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) on `VirtualMachine01` which connects and perform an action on `VirtualMachine02` both hosted in Azure.

That's the command:

```
PsExec.exe \\VirtualMachine02.publicaddres.com IISReset /restart
```

In order to allow a traffic through Azure I started with the fastest and the most insecure config. These are the rules I added on Azure in Networking panel:

- VirtualMachine01: allow all outbound traffic from any port any protocol
- VirutalMachine02: allow all inbound traffic from any port any protocol

How can I set up port rules specifically to the command I run?

I read that PsExec dynamically allocates ports but in Azure there's no way to add firewall rule like `Windows Remote Management` or `Windows COM+ Remote Administration` like you could set up directly in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the port 135,445 and dynamic port 49152-65535 to the inbound rule of the NSG attached with Virtual Machine02.

Comment: It doesn't work. Be more specific, please. What machine what kind of traffic (in, out) what protocol. I added 135,445 both machines, for 01 outbound (any protocal) for 02 inbound (any protocal). 49152-65535 only for 02 inbound.

Comment: I have two windows server 2016 datacenter, which belongs to two vnet with peering each other. Just add the port as mentioned above+RDP port the inbound rule for 02, and add RDP port for 01 only, also keep the default rules in NSG. I test it works. I suggest confirming the connectivity between 01 and 02 first, then test the PsExec port.

Comment: @mklimek except for the NSG, could you temporarily disable the windows firewall both on vm01 and vm02 when you test?

Comment: It didn't work for me as I said. I ended up connect to VirtualMachine02 by its pirvate vnet address instead of public one. Then I have still all ports open but it's a bit more secured since traffic is isnide vnet only :)

Comment: Ah~ I also use the private IP address since they are in a peered virtual network with the specific ports open above. Forget to mention that before :(